# Can't open Spatialite plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qspatialite

After installation, I got the error messages below when I click the Spatialite (V.7) Plugins:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\qspatialite.py", line 68, in run
    dlg = QspatiaLiteApp(self.iface)
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\QspatiaLiteApp.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.changeDb(max(0,self.connections['idx']))
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\QspatiaLiteApp.py", line 146, in changeDb
    self.drawTreeView()
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\QspatiaLiteApp.py", line 151, in drawTreeView
    model=self.db.createTreeModel()
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\Classes\Database.py", line 107, in createTreeModel
    self.getTables()
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\Classes\Database.py", line 81, in getTables
    header,data=self.executeQuery(query)
  File "C:\Users\uqipurna/.qgis2/python/plugins\QspatiaLite\Classes\Database.py", line 46, in executeQuery
    cursor.execute(query,params)
DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

What is going on with my installation?

Answer (score 2):

QSpatialite always tries to open the last database used. Your error message

```
DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

looks like that you tried to connect to an encrypted database. If you know what file it was, remove it to another folder. You will get a different error message, but you can then select a valid sqlite database.

Personally, I don't like the plugin, and use the database manager instead.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I found the mistake by your clue. Now, it's work fine. Thank @Andre.