# Can't define Custom CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

1) I tried to define a custom CRS in QGIS without success. I fill all fields and try to change project CRS. (all parameters is good) But I can't find custom CRS in list. I think that this is due to this error. [image: Error]

2) This window opens at startup of the program. I tried to install all versions of QGIS from 2.6 to 2.18 and this error didn't disappear.
What am I doing wrong?

3) I remove qgis.db and the error message and the error message don't open now. But I still can't define new custom CRS.I fill all fields with this parameters. [image]

When I try to change the project CRC I can't find it in list.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What does the error message say in English?

Comment: "I tried to define a custom CRS in QGIS without success. I fill all fields and try to change project " - what fields did you fill, and what values did you use?  Please outline the steps you followed to create your custom CRS.  You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: i think it might be [a duplicate of this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/83186/55203)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several parameters are stored in qgis.db (sqlite database). It seems your database file was broken. Removing qgis.db not a good idea, you will lost several functionality of QGIS. Try to reinstall QGIS or copy qgis.db from an other machine. qgis.db is in the /usr/share/qgis/resource on a Linux box.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Copying qgis.db from other machine helped me!